# Active Directory User Lookup in Lightswitch

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-lightswitch

Using Visual Studio LightSwitch 2012 Silverlight web.

I would like to add a screen that allows a user to look up AD users and select one. I can't think of a way to do this in Lightswitch without populating a table with the query results then deleting them after. Any suggestions?

I took a look at [this sample project](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/LightSwitch-Active-5092eaa8) uploaded by the Lightswitch team and it looks like to have to save the distro name first then the members table get populated. This is NOT what i want.